# How to add values of 2 rows of a duplicate row in KNIME?

Tags: group-by, data-analysis, knime

I tried using several nodes like Math Formula, Rule Engine, Duplicate row filter node. But I was unable to simply add value of 2 rows while keeping other column same as it was.

```
rowid    col0   col1   col2
  0       He     80     1
  1       He     20     1
```

So, 2 rows are duplicate above. To add 2 rows of col1 i.e 80 + 20 , while keeping col2 = 1 i.e no addition applied. How do I get the output to be? :

```
rowid   col0   col1   col2
  0      He     100     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you needed was Groupby node then apply following configuration:
Group columns: col0
Manual aggregation : col1 -> Sum, col2 ->First

And done!! It wasn't hard at all. Just lack of experience.